# Firebase and Google Chart , timestamp not accurate

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-visualization

This code is to show the temperature on the specific are and record it to the firebase database.

This code is supposedly to record current date into the database then temperature and at last , timestamp, but it instead record a different time (ex. My current data and time is May 1 , 3:11am but it instead recorded April 30 , 6pm) which result onto not showing anything into chart since the chart is set to show only the data on the same day ( if it's may 1 , the chart only shows may 1, data's )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Temperature Chart</title>
    <!-- Load Google Charts API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        // Get the temperature data from the Firebase Realtime Database
        var currentDate = getFormattedDate(new Date());
        var temperatureRef = database.ref('temperature/' + currentDate + '/temperatureData');
        var temperatureRef = firebase.database().ref('temperature');
        temperatureRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');

          snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            data.addRow([new Date(childData.timestamp), childData.temperature]);
          });

          var options = {
            chart: {
              title: 'Temperature Chart',
              subtitle: 'Past 24 hours'
            },
            width: 900,
            height: 500
          };

          var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

          chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
        });
      }
      function getFormattedDate(date) {
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        var day = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
        return year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>

    <!-- Initialize Firebase -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script>
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: ""
        authDomain: ""
        databaseURL:""
        projectId: ""
        storageBucket: ""
        messagingSenderId: ""
        appId: ""
        measurementId: ""
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

      // Get a reference to the Firebase Realtime Database
      var database = firebase.database();

      var openWeatherMapUrl = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Santa+Ana,Ph&appid=cfc8944cfa43267863bf72049929f745&units=metric';
      
      // Update the Firebase Realtime Database with the latest temperature data
      function updateDatabase() {
  // Get the current time and the start of the current day
  var currentTime = new Date();
console.log('Current time:', currentTime);
var startOfDay = new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), currentTime.getMonth(), currentTime.getDate());

  // Check if the current time is within the current day
    if (currentTime >= startOfDay) {
    // Get the current temperature from OpenWeatherMap API
    fetch(openWeatherMapUrl)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
       // Get the current date in YYYY-MM-DD format
    var currentDate = currentTime.toISOString().slice(0,10);

// Create a new database record with the temperature data for the current day
var temperatureRef = database.ref('temperature/' + currentDate).push();
temperatureRef.set({
  timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
  temperature: data.main.temp
});

// Call the drawChart function with the current day parameter
drawChart(startOfDay);
})
.catch(error => console.error(error));
}
}

      // Call the updateDatabase() function every 3 hours to update the temperature data
      setInterval(updateDatabase, 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

i tried tinkering `timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,` , like replacing it with `date.now()` or any other that should result recording the right time and date , but it didn't fix it .

Comment: what is the value of `childData.timestamp`? how is that date formatted?

Comment: @WhiteHat the format is the Parent temperature - next is data which is 2023-04-30 and then temperature data of 26.83 and timstamp of 1682880566522

Comment: maybe try adjusting the timestamp by the timezone offset -- `timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP + ((new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000)`

Comment: @WhiteHat the result become `[object Object]-28800000 `

Comment: ok, I'm not familiar with firebase, so not really sure, but you might be to correct by adjusting the timezone somehow